# kivy hello world bringing up blank screen

Tags: android, python, pip, kivy

Here is my code

```
from kivy.app import App
#kivy.require('1.10.1')

from kivy.uix.label import Label


class SimpleKivy(App): #inherit from App class
    def bulid(self):
        return Label(text="Hello World")


if __name__=="__main__":
    SimpleKivy().run()
```

All I get is a blank black screen. Nothing is printed. Here is the output in the console.

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\<my name>\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-12-11_11.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.5.0 - Build 23.20.16.4973'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.50 - Build 23.20.16.4973'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
```

It should be noted that I am running on spyder (anaconda version 4.5.11). I already ran through all the instillation steps listed in the following link, and it says the requirement has been satisfied for all of them. I have read other responses and tried other things, but nothing seems to work.

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `SimpleKivy` App, the method should be `build`, not `bulid`.